# Soma dos multiplos de 3 ou 5

Tags: java

Estou tentando construir um programa que encontre e some os múltiplos de 3 ou 5 abaixo de 1000.

O problema é que está retornando um resultado da soma que não condiz com o que eu pedi.

```
    package basicojava;

public class Multiplos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int z = 5;
        int somax = 0;
        int somaz = 0;
        int res;

        for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            if(x % i == 0) {
                somax = i + i;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            if(z % i == 0) {
                somaz = i + i;
            }
        }
        res = somax + somaz;

        System.out.println("A soma dos multiplos de 3 e 5 abaixo de 1000, é: " +res);

    }
}
```

A soma está retornando 16.

Comment: Dentro dos dois laços, troque para `somax += i + i;` dentro do primeiro e `somaz += i + i;`

Comment: Só um esclarecimento. O objetivo do programa é somar todos os múltiplos de 3 ou 5 até 1000, correto?

Comment: "If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

Comment: Então é **3 ou 5**. É porque a forma como você escreveu na pergunta da dupla interpretação, como o @acklay explicou na resposta dele, e acaba gerando uma resposta completamente diferente.

Comment: Alguém me explica o porquê de precisar multiplicar 3 x 5 = 15, achar a soma dos múltiplos de 15 compreendidos entre 1 e 1000, depois subtrair este valor da soma dos múltiplos de 3 e 5, sendo que a pergunta pede pra achar apenas a soma dos múltiplos de 3 **ou** 5 ???

Comment: @MatheusDantas 15 é multiplo dos 2, dependendo da forma que você faz você conta indevidamente duas vezes o mesmo número (uma pra multiplo de três e outra pra múltiplo de cinco em se tratando do mesmo número, dando o dobro do que deveria nestes casos - quando você tira os casos múltiplos de 15 está descontando essas duplicidades)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Segundo esta [resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691947/5524514), há um errinho na sua lógica. O correto seria dividir o `i` pelo `x` ou `z` para ver se eles são múltiplos, e somar às variáveis acumuladoras:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int x = 3;
    int z = 5;
    int somax = 0;
    int somaz = 0;
    int res;

    for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        if(i % x == 0) {
            somax += i;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        if(i % z == 0) {
            somaz += i;
        }
    }
    res = somax + somaz;

    System.out.println("A soma dos multiplos de 3 e 5 abaixo de 1000, é: " +res);
}
```

Porém, o código acima irá somar múltiplos em comum de 3 e 5 duas vezes, pois você está fazendo a somatória em laços separados, o que afetará o resultado.

Outra forma de fazer isso unificando tudo num laço e evitando o problema citado é conforme abaixo:

```
int x = 3;
int z = 5;
int res = 0;



for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    if(i % x == 0 || i % z == 0){
        res += i;
    }
}

System.out.println("A soma dos multiplos de 3 e 5 abaixo de 1000, é: " +res);
```

Veja um exemplo com multiplos até 10 no [ideone](https://ideone.com/hiB6R4), cujo resultado será 23 *(3+6+9+5=23)*.

Comment: Eu não entendi direito esse operador "=+". Poderia me explicar?

Comment: @Hardysec veja se da pra entender com esse exemplo: `a += b `  é o mesmo que `a = a + b`, você atribui o valor da esquerda a soma dele mesmo com os valores da direita. Da uma lida nesse link que explica melhor: http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/08/java-operadores-de-atribuicao-e.html

Comment: Esses operadores só existem em java? Ou alguns em outras linguagens como C?

Comment: @Hardysec você chegou a visitar o link que sugeri? Eles são do java, conforme explica lá. :)

Comment: Sim, eu visitei. Só queria saber mesmo, se há equivalentes a esses na linguagem C, já que eu a uso também para estudar lógica.

Comment: @Hardysec não manjo de C, mas esses operadores geralmente fazem a mesma coisa em todas as linguagens. As vezes tem uma particularidade em uma ou outra, mas no java é mais ou menos o que expliquei no primeiro comentario.

Comment: @Hardysec, também existem no C. Posso te dizer que no geral, boa parte das linguagens aceitam o `+=`

Comment: Só para constar, o resultado final dessas duas soluções são **diferentes** a primeira soma os múltiplos **em comum** de ambos (Ex: 15, 30). Enquanto a segunda, por estar no mesmo laço, não soma esses valores.

Comment: @Zulian não, ambas fazem a mesma coisa, a primeira só separou somando a soma dos multiplos de cada um separadamente, já na segunda o laço unico já faz isso sem precisar de 2 variaveis diferentes de soma.

Comment: Rodando o código, a primeira solução retorna a soma 266333. A segunda 233168.

Comment: Talvez não ficou claro, mas no primeiro exemplo, os valores em comum são somado **duas** vezes, enquanto no segundo somente uma.

Comment: @Zulian o OP não deixou claro isso, e o exercicio do qual ele se baseou também não deixa isso definido, logo as duas opções podem ser certas.

Comment: Concordo, porém são códigos que se diferenciam em certos aspectos e a resposta não deixa claro isso. Usuários podem se confundir pensando que fazem exatamente a mesma coisa e um é "otimização" do outro.

Comment: @Zulian foi adicionado uma observação.

Answer (score 13):

## Solução utilizando `IntStream`

A partir do Java 8 você pode utilizar a classe `IntStream` para fazer o trabalho do laço de repetição:

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.range(1, 1000);
```

O código acima gerará uma `Stream` que representa todos os números inteiros entre 1 e 1000. Para obter a soma dos valores que são múltiplos de 3 ou 5, basta filtrar pelos múltiplos de 3 ou 5 e somá-los:

```
long result = stream.filter(value -> (value % 3 == 0 || value % 5 == 0)).sum();
```

Desta forma, o valor de `result` será a soma de todos os múltiplos de 3 ou 5 entre 1 e 1000, 233.168.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/wTI8Z7).

---

## Solução matemática ❤️

Outra possível solução é analisar o problema matematicamente. Se considerarmos a soma de todos os valores que são múltiplos de 3, temos:

```
3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + ... + 993 + 996 + 999
```

Se colocarmos o termo 3 em evidência, ficamos com:

```
3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + 331 + 332 + 333)
```

Ou seja, a soma de todos os múltiplos de 3 entre 1 e 1000 é o equivalente ao triplo da soma de todos os valores inteiros entre 1 e 333, onde 333 refere-se ao maior múltiplo de 3, menor que 1000, dividido por 3. E é sabido que a soma dos números inteiros entre 1 e X vale:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + X = X*(X+1)/2
```

Generalizando, temos que a soma de todos os múltiplos de n, entre 1 e N, será:

```
S(n) = n*(N/n)*(N/n + 1)/2
```

Portanto, a soma de todos os múltiplos de 3, entre 1 e 999, será:

```
S(n=3) = 3*(999/3)*(999/3 + 1)/2 = 166.833
```

De igual forma, a soma de todos os múltiplos de 5, entre 1 e 999, será:

```
S(n=5) = 5*(999/5)*(999/5 + 1)/2 = 99.500
```

Porém, assim, os múltiplos de 15, que são múltiplos de 3 e 5, serão contabilizados duas vezes e, para se obter o valor desejado, deve-se subtrair a soma dos múltiplos de 15, entre 1 e 999:

```
S(n=15) = 15*(999/15)*(999/15 + 1)/2 = 33.165
```

Assim, a soma de todos os múltiplos de 3 ou 5, entre 1 e 999, será:

```
S = 166.833 + 99.500 - 33.165
S = 233.168
```

> **Nota:** o valor 15 é o equivalente ao MMC (Mínimo Múltiplo Comum) entre os valores 3 e 5, não necessariamente a multiplicação entre eles. O caso de 15 ser também a multiplicação dos dois fatores é "*coincidência*" por serem primos entre si.

Que é o resultado desejado. Em Java podemos fazer assim:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      
    int N = 1000;
    int result = sum(3, N-1) + sum(5, N-1) - sum(15, N-1);
    
    System.out.println(result);
  }
  
  public static int sum(int n, int N) {
      return n * (N/n) * (N/n + 1)/2;
  }
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vwRTH0).

Comment: Esse coração na solução matemática é justíssimo

Comment: Que doidera essa solução matemática. Eu nunca pensaria nisso! haha

Comment: @VítorMartins é basicamente a demonstração da soma dos elementos de uma progressão aritmética finita, só deixei assim porque achei que ficaria mais fácil de entender para quem não conhece tão a fundo a matemática.

Comment: Vale lembrar que a solução matemática (que é a que eu prefiro) só funciona se os números forem primos entre si. Por exemplo, se em vez de 3 e 5 fossem 3 e 9, aí não funcionaria, porque como todo múltiplo de 9 também é de múltiplo de 3, cai no problema de contar alguns mais de uma vez.

Comment: @hkotsubo Acho que funciona sim, mas teria que descontar os múltiplos de 9. Isto é, soma os múltiplos de 3 com múltiplos de 9 e desconta os múltiplos de 9 (mmc entre 3 e 9), que seria basicamente a soma dos múltiplos de 3. Acho que a resposta poderia deixar claro ali que 15 não é necessariamente a multiplicação dos dois, mas o MMC entre eles.

Comment: @hkotsubo Adicionei a nota, mas muito obrigado por observar isso

Answer (score 5):

**Só acrescentando,** tudo depende de interpretação, onde pode dar tudo errado.

Na pergunta fala

> ...múltiplos de 3 e 5 abaixo de 1000.

Ou seja

```
i % 3 && i % 5
```

Eu faria [desta forma](http://ideone.com/LZZJR9)<sup>ideone</sup>:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
    result = (i % n1 == 0 && i % n2 == 0)? result += i : result;
 }
```

Caso seja múltiplos de 3 **ou** 5 abaixo de 1000, isso resultaria em um resultado totalmente diferente.

Ou seja

```
i % 3 || i % 5
```

Eu faria [desta forma](http://ideone.com/bsnJKL)<sup>ideone</sup>:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
    result = (i % n1 == 0 || i % n2 == 0)? result += i : result;
 }
```

**Obs.:** O `int` estou iniciando com `1` porque somar `0` é mesma coisa de somar com nada.

Comment: hehehe, foi resolvido com uma simples gramatica, troca de E por OU na pergunta do autor rsrs

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não sei se percebeu a edição e nós comentários, mas foi bem um erro de tradução de um problema já existente. huehueBr

Answer (score 1):

A soma de números múltiplos de `n` é uma soma de progressão aritmética com razão igual a `n`.

Uma forma de reduzir a complexidade de O(n) para O(1) é usar a [fórmula](https://alunosonline.uol.com.br/matematica/soma-dos-termos-uma-pa.html) para esta soma,

```
soma_de_pa = (primeiro_elemento + enesimo_elemento) * n / 2;
```

Dessa forma, o programa desejado ficaria com a seguinte *cara*,

```
class Programa {
    public static void main(String []args){
        int primeiro_elemento = 0;

        int enesimo_elemento_multiplo_3 = 1000 - (1000 % 3);
        int enesimo_elemento_multiplo_5 = 1000 - (1000 % 5);
        int enesimo_elemento_multiplo_15 = 1000 - (1000 % 15);

        double n_multiplo_3 = Math.ceil(1000 / 3.0);
        double n_multiplo_5 = Math.ceil(1000 / 5.0);
        double n_multiplo_15 = Math.ceil(1000 / 15.0);

        double soma_multiplo_3 = (primeiro_elemento + enesimo_elemento_multiplo_3) * n_multiplo_3 / 2.0;
        double soma_multiplo_5 = (primeiro_elemento + enesimo_elemento_multiplo_5) * n_multiplo_5 / 2.0;
        double soma_multiplo_15 = (primeiro_elemento + enesimo_elemento_multiplo_15) * n_multiplo_15 / 2.0;

        // O total é a soma dos múltiplos de 3 mais a soma dos
        // múltiplos de 5, menos a soma dos múltiplos de 15, que
        // foi contabilizada duas vezes, nas duas primeiras parcelas.
        // (obrigado, Anderson Carlos Woss, pela dica!)
        double soma = soma_multiplo_3 + soma_multiplo_5 - soma_multiplo_15;

        System.out.println(soma_multiplo_3);
        System.out.println(soma_multiplo_5);
        System.out.println(soma_multiplo_15);
        System.out.println(soma);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class somaMultiplos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numeroTres = 3;
        int numeroCinco = 5;
        int somaMultiploTres = 0;
        int somaMultiploCinco = 0;
        int resultado = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if((i%numeroTres == 0)||(i%numeroCinco == 0))
                resultado += i;     

            if((i%numeroTres == 0)&&(i%numeroCinco == 0))
                resultado += i;
        }
        // vai haver momentos de existir número múltiplos de 3 e de 5 ao mesmo tempo 
        // e portanto o primeiro "if" não leva isso consideração 
        //o segundo "if" é justamente para somar os números que são múltiplos de 3 e 5 ao mesmo tempo


        System.out.println("A soma dos multiplos de 3 e 5 abaixo de 1000, é: " +resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho interessante colocar uma explicação fora do código, quem olha de relance acha que é só um monte de código jogado na tela

Comment: Principalmente explicar porquê da existência do segundo `if`, sendo que se o número for múltiplo de 3 e 5, ele já será múltiplo de 3 ou 5, entrando no primeiro `if`.

Comment: a ideia é somar múltiplos de 3 e de 5, o primeiro "if" ele vai somar ao resultado valores de que sejam múltiplos de 3 ou de 5, só que por exemplo o número 30 é múltiplo de 3 e de 5 ao mesmo tempo, então o 30 vai ser somado somente uma vez ao resultado e, eu acredito que deveria ser somado duas vezes que é a função do segundo "if"

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu exercício fazendo assim:

```
//Some todos os numeros naturais abaixo de 1000 que são múltiplos de 5 ou 3.

public class Exerc25 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //---------------variáveis
        int numero, soma = 0;
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //---------------Entrada de dados
        System.out.print("Digite um número (qualquer um, pode ser 1000): ");
        numero = teclado.nextInt();

        //---------------Processamento
        for(int i = numero-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(i % 5 == 0 | i % 3 == 0) {
                soma = soma + i;
            }
        }

        //---------------Impressão
        System.out.println("Soma: " + soma);

        teclado.close();
    }
}
```

dessa maneira o resultado é exatamente 233.168 se vc inserir 1000 como entrada.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if ( (i % 3) == 0 || (i%5) == 0 ) {
       count += i;
    }
}
// obs: Javascript
// saida: 233.168
```